# How to calculate a sum of mismatching elements in two NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

So I'm currently trying to implement a perceptron, and I have two NumPy arrays, dimensions are 1x200. I would like to check each and every element in the two matrices against each other, and get back the sum of the elements which doesn't match each other. I tried doing something like this:

```
b = (x_A > 0).astype(int)
b[b == 0] = -1
```

Now I want to compare this matrix with the other, my question is therefore, is there a way to avoid for-loops and still get what I want (the sum of elements which doesn't match)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to do this directly - assuming that your arrays are of the same dimensions. For numpy arrays `a` and `b`:

```
np.sum(a != b)
```

`a != b` gives an array of Booleans (True when they are not equal element-wise and False when they are). Sum will give you the count of all elements that are not equal.